# Codewars challenge - pair of shoes

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge

Yesterday you found some shoes in your room. Each shoe is described by two values:

- type indicates if it's a left or a right shoe;
- size is the size of the shoe.

Your task is to check whether it is possible to pair the shoes you found in such a way that each pair consists of a right and a left shoe of an equal size

For:

```
shoes = [[0, 21], 
       [1, 23], 
       [1, 21], 
       [0, 23]]
```

the output should be true;

For:

```
shoes = [[0, 21], 
       [1, 23], 
       [1, 21], 
       [1, 23]]
```

the output should be false.

So I wrote the code below,added some comments

```js
 shoes = [[0, 21], 
           [1, 23], 
           [1, 21], 
           [0, 23]];
           
  function pairOfShoes(shoes) {
        //replace 0 with -1 so I can reduce them to 0 later if they are a pair
        for (var i = 0; i < shoes.length; i++) {
            if (shoes[i][0] == 0) {
                shoes[i][0] = -1
            }
        }
        //reduce the array to object with shoe size as key
        function objectify(array) {
            return array.reduce(function(p, c) {
                p[c[1]] = (p[c[1]] != undefined ? p[c[1]] : 0) + c[0];
                return p;
            }, {});
        }
    
        var p = objectify(shoes);
        //check for each shoe size if the value is 0
        for (var x in p) {
            if (p[x] != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }         
    
 console.log(pairOfShoes(shoes));
```

Seems convoluted to me can this code be improved?

Comment: Two things I would say. (1) The use of names like p and c make it hard to understand. Use more descriptive names and assign intermediate variables (`let size=c[1]`)  to make it easier to understand. (2) Try and keep all your code in a function at the same level. If you are going to use a function `objecttify` then add a function to `changeLeftFlag` and another to `checkAllEntriesAreZero`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Convert your test values where you need them

Your initial `for` loop only sets each "right / left" value to -1 if it is 0. This can be done in the `reduce` function itself. Also, your conditional `p[c[1]] != undefined` is unnecessary, as `undefined` evaluates to false, and there is no concern here about other "falsy" values such as zero.

### Use Javascript's array methods

- `.some()` can eliminate unnecessary `for` loops with conditionals in Javascript.
- `.values()` lets you concisely iterate through values of an object.

Combined with the arrow operator `=>`, these can result in concise code that reads a little more like a natural sentence.

Applying both of the above points to your code:

```
shoes = [[0, 21], 
         [1, 23], 
         [1, 21], 
         [0, 23]];

function pairOfShoes(shoes) {
    var p = shoes.reduce(function(p, c) {
        p[c[1]] = (p[c[1]] || 0) + (c[0]==1 ? 1 : -1);
        return p;
    }, {});
    if (Object.values(p).some(x => x != 0)) { return false }
    else { return true };
}        

console.log(pairOfShoes(shoes));
```

[Edit: It might also be clearer to replace your `reduce` function with a `for' loop.]

Comment: I tested you answer it gives me false...

Comment: I'm still editing the dumb thing.

Comment: Done. And JSfiddle says it's all good.

Comment: Apparently Object.values is poorly supported on mainstream browsers, on Codewars I had to replace it with `var vals = Object.keys(p).map(function(key) {
    return p[key];` But it works,thanks for the effort.

Comment: Yeah it's probably the arrow function. That's new in ES6/ES2015.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan's answer is great (and already accepted). This is just to show a few tricks:

```
const allPairs = (shoes) => {
  const pairings = shoes.reduce((pairings, shoe) => {
    const [type, size] = shoe;
    pairings[size] = (pairings[size] || 0) + (type ? +1 : -1);
    return pairings;
  }, {});
  return !Object.values(pairings).some(value => value);
};
```

The above uses the `const` keyword, rather than `var`, as it's generally better to use the stronger declaration when possible.

It also uses array destructuring to assign `type` and `size`, which makes the code a little clearer than using numeric indices.

Finally, rather than writing an `if..else` for the return values, it just negates the result of `some` and returns it directly; it's already a boolean. It also skips comparing to zero in the `some` callback; zero is falsey already.